# Python using for loops to do a groupby is too slow, faster way?

Tags: python, performance, loops

I have a unique list of integers extracted from the first index of each tuple in `l2`.

I am trying to do something like a `groupby` in `l2` on the first index of the tuple (i.e each item in the unique list) so I can count the number of occurrences that the second index of the tuple in `l2` exist in `l3`. - please see the example.

To do this, I have a dictionary set up for each item in the unique list and it resets after each loop. The dict key is each value in `l3`.

My code works fine, it is just very slow when I have a ton of data because of the many loops.

Any way to make this more efficient and fast?

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [(1,'a'),(3,'c'),(3,'b'),(2,'b'),(1,'a'),(3,'a')]
l3 = ['a','b']

d = defaultdict(int)
for i in l1:
    d = d.fromkeys(d, 0) # reset dict values to 0
    for t in l2:
        if i==t[0]:
           if t[1] in l3:
               d[t[1]] +=1
    print d
```

Example:

```
when i == 1:
d = {'a':2,'b':0}
```

Comment: What are the real numbers? How large are l1 and l3, specifically?

Comment: I get key error: `KeyError: 'a'` probably because you re-create a standard dictionary (not a defaultdict) overwriting d. So your [mcve] doesn't work.

Comment: Length of l1 can go to 30000. L2 even more cos it's not distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `l3` a *set* for fast membership testing. Put all `l1`-based counters into a dictionary; that way you don't need to loop over `l1` *at all* and just use the `t[0]` value to select the right counter:

```
counts = {i: defaultdict(int) for i in l1}
s3 = set(l3)
for t0, t1 in l2:
    # only count if t[1] is included in l3, and t[0] is in l1
    if t1 not in s3 or t0 not in counts:
        continue
    counts[t0][t1] += 1

for d in counts.itervalues():
    print d
```

This removes two multipliers; `len(l1)` and `len(l3)`, so what was once a O(NKM) loop is now a O(K) loop.

This does increase the memory requirements, as you now need to track `len(l1)` `defaultdict` objects. Allocating the memory for those objects up-front will take some time too.

Answer (score 0):

I would combine a defaultdict with a Counter:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
```

Then you can query whatever you want:

```
>>> grouper = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for n, c in l2:
...     grouper[n][c] += 1
...
>>> grouper[1]
Counter({'a': 2})
>>> grouper[2]
Counter({'b': 1})
>>> grouper[3]
Counter({'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'a': 1})
>>> grouper[3]['a']
1
>>> grouper[3]['b']
1
```

Comment: The counter doesn't add anything here; using a `Counter` instead of a `defaultdict` is not very useful unless you plan to use other Counter-specific functionality.

Comment: You do need to filter on `l3` first. There is also no guarantee that `n` is in `l1`, so should not be counted.

Comment: Well, I suppose it could have just as easily been `defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))` or just use `defaultdict(dict)` with `.setdefault(c,0) + 1`.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting the question: why is it necessary to filter on `l3`?

Comment: But again, that assumes that **all** values in `t[0]` are to be counted. The OP is only counting those values that appear in `l1`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see. I didn't originally interpret it as being an absolute requirement *not* to count values outside of `l3`. If my goal was to "count the number of occurrences that the second index of the tuple in l2 exist in l3. " I would just do what I did in the answer and not worry about the extra counts...